# Runnable not running

Tags: java, android, handler, runnable

I am writing a program that calculates pi with a given amount of iterations. I want to be able to time how long this takes and how much power is being used. I have another version of this application that works perfectly but, with the same code, this version won't.
Most of the code is working fine but the powerRunnable code is not executing when it is called.
any thoughts?

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
//GUI
TextView piResultTextView, timeResultTextView,
        powerResultTextView, voltageTextView, averageCurrentTextView;
EditText piEditText;
Button calculateButton, stopButton;
TextView countView;

//GLOBAL VARIABLES
Results results;

Handler powerHandler = new Handler();
Runnable powerRunnable = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "here", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        long millis = System.currentTimeMillis() - results.initialTime;
        timeResultTextView.setText(getString(R.string.display_time, millis));

        double current = getCurrent();
        results.totalCurrent += current;
        results.count++;

        double power = current * results.voltage;
        results.powerConsumption += power;


        countView.setText(String.valueOf(results.count));


        powerHandler.postDelayed(this, 1);
    }
};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    piEditText = findViewById(R.id.PiEditText);
    calculateButton = findViewById(R.id.CalculateButton);
    calculateButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (!empty()) {
                results = new Results(getVoltage());
                results.initialTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                powerHandler.postDelayed(powerRunnable, 0);

                calculatePi(piEditText.getText().toString());
                finalizeResults();
                displayResults();
            }
        }
    });
    stopButton = findViewById(R.id.StopButton);
    stopButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            piResultTextView.setText("");
            timeResultTextView.setText("");
            powerResultTextView.setText("");
            voltageTextView.setText("");
            averageCurrentTextView.setText("");

            powerHandler.removeCallbacks(powerRunnable);
        }
    });
    piResultTextView = findViewById(R.id.PiResultTextView);
    timeResultTextView = findViewById(R.id.TimeResultTextView);
    powerResultTextView = findViewById(R.id.PowerResultTextView);
    voltageTextView = findViewById(R.id.VoltageTextView);
    averageCurrentTextView = findViewById(R.id.AverageCurrentTextView);

    countView = findViewById(R.id.CountView);
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    powerHandler.removeCallbacks(powerRunnable);
}

public void finalizeResults() {
    results.endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    powerHandler.removeCallbacks(powerRunnable);
    results.powerConsumption *= 1000;
}

public void displayResults() {
    piResultTextView.setText(results.pi);
    timeResultTextView.setText(getString(R.string.display_time, results.getTime()));
    powerResultTextView.setText(getString(R.string.display_power, results.powerConsumption));
    voltageTextView.setText(getString(R.string.display_voltage, results.getVoltage()));
    averageCurrentTextView.setText(getString(R.string.display_current, results.getAverageCurrent()));
}
}
```

Comment: It seems you need to call `powerRunnable.start();`

Comment: brian is right thread should call start to do their task you should have forget that

Comment: I dont see any powerHandler.postDelayed(powerRunnable, 1) to start it

Comment: try passing 1000 or more appropiate value instead of 1 to `Handler.postDelayed()` method

Comment: powerRunnable.start() only invokes it once, I need it to run every millisecond.
powerHandler.postDelayed(powerRunnable, 1) is invoked when the calculate button is pressed

Comment: Does the first call `powerHandler.postDelayed(powerRunnable, 0)` work?
What exactly does the `empty()` method check?

Comment: no it hasn't worked unfortunately. 
The Empty() method just checks the edit text has data inputted to it before calculations can be performed

Answer (score 0):

I try to use your part of code in my application:

```
Handler powerHandler = new Handler();
Runnable powerRunnable = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "here", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        powerHandler.postDelayed(this, 1);
    }
};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
    ButterKnife.bind(this);

    powerHandler.postDelayed(powerRunnable, 0);
}
```

And its working.

Comment: What is `ButterKnife.bind(this)` ?

Comment: `ButterKnife` is a library for automatic mapping from layout on views. http://jakewharton.github.io/butterknife/
You can skip it.